# "viewWillTransitionToSize:" not called in iOS 9 when the view controller is presented modally

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, screen-orientation, autorotate, presentviewcontroller

I present a view controller from another one:

```
- (void)showModalView
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   MySecViewController *mySecViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secController"];
   mySecViewController.delegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:mySecViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in the presented `UIViewController`, the method `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` is called in `iOS 8` but not in `iOS 9`...

Thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 28):

In your current view controller, if you override `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, make sure you call `super`. Otherwise, this message won't get propagated to children view controllers.

For **Objective-C**:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Your other code ...
```

And **Swift**:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    // Your other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

People have already explained that you have to call **super**. I'd like to add a piece of information that might help people who would have faced what i faced.

### Scenario: Parent -> Child (viewWillTransition not called in child)

---

If your view controller is a *child* view controller, then check if the *parent* view controller delegate is called and if super is called there. **Otherwise it won't be propagated to the child view controller!**

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    func presentChild() {
        let child = ChildViewController()
        present(child, animated: false, compeltion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator) // If this line is missing your child will not get the delegate call in it's viewWillTransition

        // Do something
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    // This method will not get called if presented from parent view controller and super is not called inside the viewViewWillTransition available there.
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

       //Do something
    }
}
```

---

P.S - This happened to me because the code for the parent was written by someone else and they forgot to call super.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. But super is generally used for superClass. But here I can see a different utility for super.

Answer (score 3):

May seem a trivial case, but when using an iPad check that the user has not activated rotation lock in the settings or control panel or side button

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a little late, but I put this here for anyone stumbling upon this frustrating issue.

Keep in mind that `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` sometimes gets called on the `presentingViewController` of the view controller you are expecting it to. (And if that view controller has a `presentingViewController` too, it may get called on that)

I couldn't really figure out the logic behind this, but that was the point in my case. So I had to override `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` in many of my view controllers like this:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [self.presentedViewController viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```