# Swift viewWillTransition not called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview, viewwilltransitiontosize

I'm creating a full screen image gallery using a `UICollectionView`. When the user rotates the device, I perform updates to the `UICollectionView` within

`func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`

I present this `UIViewController` modally and have a `UICollectionView` taking up the full screen. Within `viewDidLoad`, I create the flow layout as:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
photosCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
photosCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
```

I also have the size as:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return photosCollectionView.frame.size
}
```

When I rotate my device, `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` is never called, which causes the `UICollectionViewLayout` to not update. While I rotate the device, I do get the message:

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
```

I've read online that I can add:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

to the `UIViewController`, but that had no affect. There are no content or section insets with the `UICollectionView`.

I also have the `super.viewWillTransition` called within the function as well. Can anyone assist me on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: The error message talks about "the item height". I don't see your code that determines that. Could you show it?

Comment: When I set the size, that's the height and the width. I set the `sizeForItem` at `IndexPath` = `photosCollectionView.frame.size`.

Comment: Okay, but if you say that at the wrong time, I can imagine that you might get a size where one or both dimensions is bigger than the collection view eventually becomes.

Comment: It's set using the `UICollectionViewDelegate` function `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are just concern about the layout when the device rotate then please use:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

From apple docs:

```
public func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

> This method is called when the view controller's view's size is
> changed by its parent (i.e. for the root view controller when its
> window rotates or is resized).
> If you override this method, you should either call super to propagate the change to children or manually forward the change to
> children.

I guess you might called this function on a parent of that view without calling super

A work around would also be to register for the device rotation:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    print(orientation)
}
```

Comment: That is a possibility, but it doesn't explain why the `viewWillTransition` function isn't called. Makes me wonder if I have a setting wrong.

Comment: as it says in the docs it should be called unless you called it on a parent without calling super so instead of going to your code i would suggest the way above

Comment: I have double checked all of the `super` functions have been called. I have also tested with iPads, and for some reason the `viewWillTransition` is called with no problems on the iPad, just not iPhone.

Comment: @MikeWalker I still don't know why it's not called but I tried to provide a work around solution

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the work around solution, but I'll also keep looking into why the function isn't called.

Comment: `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` notifications are not just posted for rotations, they are also posted if device goes from being vertical to horizontal

Comment: @MikeWalker `viewWillTransition` not called, may be because your view controller add as child `viewController` and `viewWillTransition` is also called in parent `viewController`

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to repost an answer which i left in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552900/7734643) which describes the same issue.

---

People have already explained that you have to call **super**. I'd like to add a piece of information that might help people who would have faced what i faced.

### Scenario: Parent -> Child (viewWillTransition not called in child)

---

If your view controller is a *child* view controller, then check if the *parent* view controller delegate is called and if super is called there. **Otherwise it won't be propagated to the child view controller!**

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    func presentChild() {
        let child = ChildViewController()
        present(child, animated: false, compeltion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator) // If this line is missing your child will not get the delegate call in it's viewWillTransition

        // Do something
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    // This method will not get called if presented from parent view controller and super is not called inside the viewViewWillTransition available there.
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

       //Do something
    }
}
```

---

P.S - This happened to me because the code for the parent was written by someone else and they forgot to call super.

Comment: Very Useful --> `super.viewWillTransition`

Answer (score 4):

I replaced

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

by

```
func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

and it works for me.

Comment: This works for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed that:

Go to Project Target - General -  Deployment Info

Tick Device Orientations the app supports

Also you need (change `UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all` for whatever is appropriate):

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all;
    }
}
```

for ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ViewController` is a child `ViewController` and you have added it’s view to a parent `ViewController`’s view, do the following:

In parent `ViewController` where you added

```
self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
```

Also add

```
self.addChild(childViewController)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to set `Supported interface orientations` in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
```