# Collection view with different cell types: how to resize some of them when orientation changes?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, rotation, orientation, uicollectionviewcell

I have registered 2 different custom `UICollectionViewCell` types:

```
collectionView.register(CustomCell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
collectionView.register(CustomCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

For one of those types of cells, I need it to have a size in portrait different from its size in landscape (I have 2 sections, and each one is populated with cells of one type), and I implemented `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` like this:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    }

    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) {
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    }

    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

Screenshot for portrait:

[image]

Screenshot for landscape:

[image]

This seems to work on `iOS 11` (orange cells are resized when I rotate the device), but I get some weird messages in `Xcode` like this:

> [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

On the other hand, this doesn't work at all on `iOS 10` (orange cells are not resized).

Which is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Did you try sizeclasses or not?

Comment: look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170373/swift-viewwilltransition-not-called