# In SwiftUI, how do you perform a code before the interface orientation change?

Tags: swift, swiftui, orientation

I need to execute a code before the device's interface starts rotating but I can't seem to find any viable solution.

I came across `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` but couldn't find anything like that to be notified that an orientation change will start.

I tried creating an `UIViewControllerRepresentable` with a custom `UIViewController` that overrides `func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`, but that function doesn't get invoked at all (I didn't forget to propagate it using super).

Any idea?

**EDIT**: Needs support for iOS 15.0+

**EDIT 2**: This is needed in a SwiftUI app (so not UIKit)

Comment: Why does it have to be *before* the orientation changes? Might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do, by detecting this?

Comment: @Sweeper: I have an `Image` and some other views placed on top of it. When rotating the interface it snaps to the correct place only after the rotation animation is completed. If I can perform code before the animation happens, I can programmatically place it in the correct spot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a regular `UIViewController` that `post`'s a `Notification` you can `onReceive` the notification after you `subscribe`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TransitionNotificationView: View {
    typealias SizeData = TransitionVM.SizeData
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .subscribeToTransition() //subscribe
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .willTransitionSize), perform: { notification in
                guard let object = notification.object as? SizeData else {return}

                print("received size Transision \(object.size.debugDescription)")
            })
    }
}
#Preview {
    TransitionNotificationView()
}
```

The code behind this is pretty standard.

```
extension View {
    func subscribeToTransition() -> some View {
        modifier(TransitionVM())
    }
}
struct TransitionVM: ViewModifier {
    typealias TraitData = Transition_UI.TraitData
    typealias SizeData = Transition_UI.SizeData
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(Transition_UI().frame(width: 0, height: 0))
    }
    
    struct Transition_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        typealias TraitData = (newCollection: UITraitCollection, coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
        typealias SizeData = (size: CGSize, coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
            TransitionVC(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
            
        }
        class TransitionVC: UIViewController {
            ///UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a presented view controller’s view.
            override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
                print(#function)
                super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .willTransitionSize, object: (size, coordinator))
                
            }
            ///UIKit calls this method before changing the current object’s **traits**
            override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
                super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
                print(#function)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .willTransitionTrait, object: (newCollection, coordinator))
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {

    static let willTransitionTrait = Notification.Name("willTransitionTrait")
    static let willTransitionSize = Notification.Name("willTransitionSize")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you're calling super. Have you ensured that you're calling `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in your `UIViewController`'s parent as well? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552927/9254309) to a similar question mentions that.

Comment: I'm integrating that view inside SwiftUI using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, and the `UIViewController` I'm calling it on is the first one I have access to. I can't tell if (probably yes) SwiftUI is attaching it to another one as a child.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this could help you:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool
```

make sure your AppDelegate, RootViewController And UINavigationController all have this override function.

Comment: When I do this in my `UIApplicationDelegate` I get the following error: `Property does not override any property from its superclass`. Also I'm in a SwiftUI project, so I don't have access to the underlying `RootViewController` and `UINavigationController`